# having a heart problem in Germany

Tags: attachment-ambiguity

a. Any company that has at least two production plants in Germany should be informed.

b. Any company with at least two production plants in Germany should be informed.

The normal interpretation would be that the company might or might not be in Germany but the production plants are.

But is it at all possible to use those sentences if the company is in Germany and the plants are not?

I think the rule says that the 'in Germany' modifies 'production plants', but do native speakers always respect the rule?

What do you think of

c. Any person with a heart problem in Germany will benefit from this new policy.

d. Any person who has a heart problem in Germany will benefit from this new policy.

?

I find (c) strange and (d) seems to be about any person who gets a heart problem in Germany ("in Germany" seems to me to modify 'has a heart problem" and is adverbial).

Answer (score 1):

Just as in:

> c. Any person with a heart problem in Germany will benefit from this new policy.
>
> d. Any person who has a heart problem in Germany will benefit from this new policy.

"in Germany" is locative and refers to "any person with a heart problem" and "who has a heart problem", in:

> a. Any company that has at least two production plants in Germany should be informed.
>
> b. Any company with at least two production plants in Germany should be informed.

"in Germany" is also locative and refers to the location, not the nationality of the company.

If you want to make it sound as if the company or the person are German, then a different text would be required:

a1. Any German company / Any company in Germany that has at least two production plants should be informed.

b1. Any German company / Any company in Germany with at least two production plants should be informed.

c1. Any German with a heart problem will benefit from this new policy.

d1. Any German who has a heart problem will benefit from this new policy.